PB50 will not use the entire roll of media
We have a PB50 printer that consistently will not use the entire roll of media. The tension on the roll lessens as the roll is used, and eventually the printer fails to feed the remaining media (usually ~10-20% of the roll).
We have cleaned the printer, changed media, confirmed that the guides are in place. Swapping with another printer allows our users to resume printing normally (even with the remaining/partial roll). Are there any adjustments or lesser-known cleaning points that I can look at? Thanks in advance for any suggestions!
